Rails – custom renderer for turbo stream?
I’m surprised that Rails does not seem to extend custom renderers to turbo streams.
Given a custom renderer :foo, in controllers you can do:
render foo: ...

But it won’t let you do:
turbo_stream.update(..., foo: ...)

If you try, it will raise “You invoked render but did not give any of :body, :file, :html, :inline, :partial, :plain, :renderable, or :template option.”
Presumably, that’s because calls to turbo-stream actions already happen as part of another call to render with the option :turbo_stream.
I could write my own custom turbo-stream action (turbo_stream.foo(...)), but that doesn’t really seem like the right place for that and it wouldn’t be as idiomatic.
Is there any way to get the syntax I want?

turbo invokes a render helper method that you'd use from the view. it is different from controller render method. custom renderers only work in a controller.
